# Problem while using walk navigation

Tags: navigation

I'm using Blender 2.92.0.

I'm just working with the default cube. Everything in walk navigation is working in my pc, but when i'm pressing spacebar for teleporting, when using walk navigation, nothing happens, nothing at all. Same goes with jumping(shortcut is V). I've searched for solution on youtube.. but nothing is there regarding teleportation and jumping using walk nav.

How do i **teleport** and **jump** when using walk navigation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a floor underneath you to 'stand' on.  Try creating a plane and scaling it up, then look at it in walk mode and press spacebar.